# how to use async await with https post request

Tags: node.js, https, request, node-modules

I am finding way out to use async / await with https post. Please help me out. I have posted my https post code snippet below.how do I use async await with this.

```
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  todo: 'Buy the milk'
})

const options = {
  hostname: 'flaviocopes.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```

Answer (score 82):

Basically, you can write a function which will return a `Promise` and then you can use `async`/`await` with that function. Please see below:

```
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  todo: 'Buy the milk'
});

const options = {
  hostname: 'flaviocopes.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  },
};

async function doSomethingUseful() {
  // return the response
  return await doRequest(options, data);
}


/**
 * Do a request with options provided.
 *
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {Object} data
 * @return {Promise} a promise of request
 */
function doRequest(options, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let responseBody = '';

      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        responseBody += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(responseBody));
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });

    req.write(data)
    req.end();
  });
}
```

Comment: I was wondering, if you declare the `doRequest` function to be `async`, wouldn't it be equal to enclosing the code inside a promise?

Comment: I have a question for `req.write(data)`. Doesn't it cause **write after end** error? What does it do here? (I am not really familiar with NodeJS, I though `write` is used to write file/print to consle)

Comment: @Mooncrater  Interesting, but how would you define where to resolve and where to reject? Can you point to an example? Cheers.

Comment: OK.  But none of these answers seem to handle the case of assigning a variable.  let result = myFunction in any form never works.  Always undefined.  Just want to have the code act like a procedure language.

Comment: @zakariah1 I don't think such a solution is possible for something as inherently asynchronous as network requests. I think the best solution would be to make `doRequest()` async, and later use something like `let response = await doRequest();` to think about the asynchronous nature as little as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  I'll. let you know how it goes.  Thank you

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem also, found this post, and used the solution from Rishikesh Darandale ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951091/how-to-use-async-await-with-https-post-request/56122489#56122489)).

The [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) documentation states *The await operator is used to wait for a Promise*. Returning the promise from a function is not required. You can just create a promise and call await on it.

```
async function doPostToDoItem(myItem) {

    const https = require('https')

    const data = JSON.stringify({
        todo: myItem
    });

    const options = {
        hostname: 'flaviocopes.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/todos',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': data.length
        },
    };

    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            let responseBody = '';

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                responseBody += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                resolve(JSON.parse(responseBody));
            });
        });

        req.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });

        req.write(data)
        req.end();
    });

    return await p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await with Promises only and Node's core https module does not have build in **promise** support. So you first have to convert it into the **promise** format and then you can use async-await with it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

This module has converted the core http module into promisified version. You can use this.

Comment: *request-promise has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142*

Comment: -1, Also, what is the point of using thr standard `https` package if you pull in an npm package to use it with? The whole point of using `https` is to not add bloated dependencies.