# Assign a HTTP response body as variable for my hapi.js handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback, hapi

How do I assign a variable from the HTTP response body of an HTTP request? I tried doing it like this, but it's getting a 502 error.

```js
const https = require('https')
const getDadJokes = async (request, h) => {
    const dadJokesApi = {
        hostname: 'icanhazdadjoke.com',
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/', 
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'text/plain',
        },
    }
    const dadJokes = https.request(dadJokesApi, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (body) => body);
    });
    dadJokes.end();
    const response = h.response(dadJokes);
    return response;
};
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this code?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951091/how-to-use-async-await-with-https-post-request) should help.

Comment: Consuming the icanhazdadjoke.com API in the form of plain text. Later, the text is to provide a response from my node.js application which is requested from the /dad-jokes path.